# Using TableView instead of ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

For creating a login page or something like that, in autolayout case I use tableView instead of using a scrollView in viewController. For IndexPath majority cases I reuse the customCell. For entirely different items only I use another customCell. Since the Cell Class are increasing in my project. I dont know is it a good practice. Please share your opinion to increase the overall performance and least memory usage for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Putting UITableView in all views is not a good practice every time.
I recommend using scrollviews and content views inside them in pages like login.

Use Tableviews only in those screens which show repeated contents.
I have seen codes generated through tableview controllers in every page.
I dont do in that way.

Better you go for Scrollviews.. Its a good method as far as I have seen.